# Search Drupal source/plaintext?

Tags: search

I'm looking for a simple way to search thru the plaintext/source of hundreds of nodes. I need to find-replace all the color settings for a certain font awesome icon (`fa-check`), but can't find any good way to check our source for which pages are using that icon. New Drupal admin here, haven't really done any dev work, so answer that doesn't require installing new modules would be great.

We're using Solr for search, incidentally.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [Scanner](https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner) module:

> Versions 5.x-2, 6.x, and 7.x of Search and Replace Scanner can do
>   plain text search-and-replace, or regular expression
>   search-and-replace, against the title, body and text content fields on
>   all nodes in your system. This is useful for finding html strings that
>   Drupal's normal search will ignore. The module is very handy if you
>   are fixing typos in a lot of content, changing the name of your
>   company, or are changing the URL of a link included multiple times in
>   multiple nodes, among other things.